# Nested IF Statement…

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a first scheduled date of 9/10/21.  I want to derive two checkpoint dates from one statement...

The first depending on the amount of time that has passed until the acceptance date.  I already have set up a formula for days past due...

```
 =IF(A2<>"",TODAY()-A2,"")     , which results in…
```

```
DATE    DAYS PAST DUE
9/10    2
```

Building upon that…  Continue from that point and count how many days until the 2nd checkpoint has been made.

I'm thinking I should use a nested IF statement.  But I don't know how to make the 1st IF statement.   Something similar to...

```
 =IF(AND(**???...**,IF(A2<>"",TODAY()-A2,"")
```

Comment: An example of your data would be helpful, including what the expected result should be for the two checkpoints.

Comment: Hi Scott,

Thank you for correcting my question.  

In the future, I want to learn the process on how you made those corrections.  Once I know this, there will be no need for correction.  

I don't know the process on cutting and pasting an example of my problem to let the stack overflow community view my problem.

So, what is the process?  Can you direct me in terms of the steps that you made in the corrections?

Thank you,

Charles

Comment: I don't know how to send an example of my data.  Do you know how to send an example of my data PeterT?

And I have revised my question below…

I have two dates that I have to keep track of.  But the second date doesn't come into effect until the first date has been has passed.  Once the first date is accomplished; I want to use that date as the starting point of the second date; and have a running count of the days until the second date has been accomplished.

Comment: You can create a spreadsheet of sample data and take a screenshot of it, then add that screenshot to your post. Or you can add a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) to your post with the data with expected results.